# Embedded python not running on Windows laptop

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run an embedded python application which runs well on desktop computers but on a laptop it is giving errors.

Initial error was:

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll is
>   missing from your computer.

On installing above, it gives error that `api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll` is missing.

How far this will go? What is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the developers have used some version of C++ to create their programs and the programs require some runtime files (Dynamic Linked Libraries) to be present in order to install/run and the developers do not include those files with their installation (why not?) and the websites for the programs often do not list the prerequisites and requirements of what you need to have installed for their programs to work.

Read more here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/missing-api-ms-win-core-timezone-i1-1-0dll/3754703c-241c-451a-a9b6-e690399fc83e

Try installing the missing files.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I get all dll files that may be needed for different systems? The links you mention provide installers only, not actual dll files.

Comment: Its mentioned in the help forum that these installers may contain all the .dll files as part of the installation.

Comment: Can I extract dll files from these installers to be distributed along with application?

Comment: Just google the DLL you need and download it individually, just figure out where in your system folder it needs to go. Then if you want to include it as part of your application you can. https://www.sts-tutorial.com/sites/downloadCenter.php?api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0